# how to give space between buttons vertically in html?

Tags: html

for example in the given code i want spaces between '1' button and '4' button , '2' button and '5' button , '3' button and '6' button so on such as there are spaces between '1' button and '2' button .

```
<div class="text-center">
<form  method="post"  action="#" name="cal">
    
    
    
    <input type="button" value=" 1 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '1'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 2 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '2'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 3 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '3'" ><br>
    <input type="button" value=" 4 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '4'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 5 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '5'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 6 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '6'" ><br>
    <input type="button" value=" 7 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '7'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 8 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '8'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 9 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '9'" ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="=" class="btn btn-outline-dark" >
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried your code with two `<br>`'s, worked well https://jsfiddle.net/fec65xzt/

Comment: Do you want left top right or bottom margins?

Comment: @crazyyou Abusing `<br>` is not good practice. Margin is better.

Comment: @Spectric I know, but he said "...in html". Alternatively he can use <p>, which actually is not better :P

Answer (score 1):

use margin it will help you make spaces between your button

```
 .btn{
    margin:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

button {
margin : 10px;   #you can increase or decrease this value to adjust the spaces you can also use margin-bottom,margin-top,margin-right,margin-left to adjust spaces of individual side.
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="text-center">
<form  method="post"  action="#" name="cal">
    
    
    
    <input type="button" value=" 1 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '1'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 2 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '2'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 3 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '3'" ><br>
    <input type="button" value=" 4 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '4'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 5 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '5'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 6 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '6'" ><br>
    <input type="button" value=" 7 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '7'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 8 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '8'" >
    <input type="button" value=" 9 " class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="cal.expression.value += '9'" ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="=" class="btn btn-outline-dark" >
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```